# Face Detection in native with OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, opengl-es, android-ndk

Can I create a face detection app for Android but writing the code in C++ instead of Java? I'm thinking of using [this code](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html).

If yes, I have a second question: As I am native and the face is detected, can I render a 3D Object with OpenGL in the face area?

Comment: i don't think, you'll gain anything by this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Thank you for your fast response :)

Comment: OpenCV has a [Java API](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) for android.

Comment: I know but I want to do this in native for better performance.

Comment: why do you think it would be faster ?

Comment: Java is fairly fast. You can wrap c++ classes for use in Android, as stated in the link I posted above.

Comment: @berak, OpenCV is written in C++. By using it native I wont call every opencv method through the jni. So am I able to use the code in the question in an Android app? And what about the second question? I'm newbie at OpenCV and wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: the java version is already calling the c++ code. you'd save almost nothing.

Comment: Well in this case I'll use Java. Thank you.
Anyway, let's say I detect a face in Java with the haar classifier, can I render a 3D object on top of the face?

Comment: Why aren't you answering? I'm searching for days and didn't find anything..

Comment: People are not answering, because you're not paying for their time. The answer is probably "yes".

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. It's just really important.